# Laravel FormRequest is modifying the input

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-formrequest

I am having trouble using the Laravel Validator to validate some data. The validator is modifying properties of the input to null.
The data passed to be validated is a mix of array and objects (in this case, a model instance).

> **Just for clarification: I know how to use FormRequest in controllers, I am full aware that Laravel would inject the FormRequest in the methods, and FormRequest is primaly to be used to validate user data, etc, etc. The point is why the validator need to modify the data I sent to validation?**

Here's an example that you can directly paste in a `php artisan tinker` session:

```php
$rules = [
    'users' => [
        'required',
        'array',
        'min:1',
    ],
    'users.*' => [
        'required',
    ],
    'users.*.name' => [
        'required',
        'string',
        'max:255',
    ],
    'users.*.age' => [
        'required',
        'integer',
    ],
    'users.*.best_friend' => [
        'required',
    ],
];

$data = [
    'users' => [
        (new \App\Models\User)->forceFill([
            'name' => 'USER #1',
            'age' => 30,
            'best_friend' => (new \App\Models\User)->forceFill(['name' => 'User X'])
        ]),
    ],
];

echo 'BEFORE: ' . data_get($data, 'users.0.name');  // USER #1
$validator = Validator::make($data, $rules);
echo 'AFTER: ' . data_get($data, 'users.0.name');   // NULL
dd($data);
```

OK, the data PASSES. But the problem is that the validation modified the variable `$data`, setting `null` to the fields with these patterns: `users.*.name`, `users.*.age` and `users.*.best_friend`.
If I dare to validate any model attribute, it sets to null.

I debugged and I reached the source of the modification:

`/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Validation/ValidationData.php:42`:

```
/**
 * Gather a copy of the attribute data filled with any missing attributes.
 *
 * @param  string  $attribute
 * @param  array  $masterData
 * @return array
 */
protected static function initializeAttributeOnData($attribute, $masterData)
{
    $explicitPath = static::getLeadingExplicitAttributePath($attribute);

    $data = static::extractDataFromPath($explicitPath, $masterData);

    if (! str_contains($attribute, '*') || str_ends_with($attribute, '*')) {
        return $data;
    }

    // here some debug info:
    // $explicitPath="users"
    // $attribute="users.*.name"
    // $data=User

    return data_set($data, $attribute, null, true);
}
```

I know `data_set` modifies by reference.
But I could not understand why the code modifies the data if there is data already there. Should not it check for data before setting to null?

The validator is making the validated properties of my model to be null. Why and how to fix?
Maybe a different approach? Maybe this could be considered an bug/improvement for the Illuminate lib?

Any help would be apreciated.

VERSIONS:
**Laravel Framework 9.33.0**

**PHP 8.1.2**

Comment: How do you pass the validation with `null` values while you add `required` rule ?

Comment: @A.Khaled the data I passed initially had no null values. Thats why It passed the validation. The problem is the Laravel Validator is modifying the validated input attributes with null values. I would use the user model instance somewhere in my code, but I am having issues with that properties modified by the Validator.

Comment: Can you share your real code? The form request or the validator and the creation logic

Comment: Actually the code is almost the one I post above. You may copy the entire code and paste it in a tinker session. Both FormRequest and Validator::make does the same result: modifies the input

Comment: @A.Khaled just in case you're curious, I am using formRequest classes to validate objects before I call a service. This makes my service classes cleaner without the validation logic. And I prefer to use laravel Validator because I think It is powerful and easier to use.

Answer (score 1):

Laravel transforms the keys from your validation rules: name and age. But that didn't work as expected because users are objects. To solve that you need to call `toArray()` after `forceFill`

```php
$data = [
    'users' => [
        (new \App\Models\User) -> forceFill([
            'name' => 'USER #1',
            'age' => 30,
            'best_friend' => (new \App\Models\User) -> forceFill(['name' => 'User X'])
        ])->toArray(),
    ]
];
```

If you need validation for `best_friend.name` you need to call `toArray()` on that too. But without validation you will get the object as it is.

Comment: I used the solution you proposed, unfortunately some properties may not be included to the validation array because of the model's "hidden" properties. I created a generic class that is responsible to pass the data to the validator, so I cannot rely in the "toArray". I know that the model provides other methods to return these data "as they are" which would work as you proposed. The problem I see calling a model method is that I must deeply traverse the array looking for a model instance to call It.

Comment: I still thinking that the validator should not modify the data It received. Instead It should make a copy for himself.

Comment: You can’t pass objects to validator. Try to pass arrays or strings